# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (in Windows Service)

Tags: c#, oracle

I write windows service and try connect to Oracle database in windows service , i connect to database with 'winform' or 'webform' correctly but when use windows service got this error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Comment: Did you even try to google it or debug your code ?

Comment: How i can debug windows service ?????

Comment: Did you try to google "How i can debug windows service?" ?

Comment: i sure when i trying to open connection , got this error

Comment: just please debug the code and google "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". I bet you will find an answer cuz it is not something new. Could you do that first?

Comment: Yes i do , but my connectionString is correct and work in winapp and webapp but in winservice no work correctly

Comment: Could you please provide the contents of `tnsnames,ora` file or your EZCONNECT connection string?

Comment: What I do not know

Comment: this work on my PC and database on server but when publish on server its not work .

Comment: Which provider do you use to connect to Oracle?

Comment: ADO , System.Data.OracleClient